# Cross-domain issues when using API from script on same domain but included from different one

Tags: javascript, json, cross-domain, jsonp, asp.net-web-api

I have developed a JavaScript file, which am I hosting. This JavaScript file is calling a Web API, which I also host (I can host it in the same domain).

The thing is, I want to my friend to call this JavaScript file from his website in a tag like this:

```
<script src="http://example.com/myJSfile.js"></script>
```

That is, my friend’s website (`myfriendwebsite.com`) will include `http://example.com/myJSfile.js`, which will call my Web API also located at `example.com`.

Will I have cross domain issues, and need to use JSONP or some similar workaround?

Comment: Yes, you will have cross-domain issues.

Comment: The location of the script is irrelevant. It's the domain of the page that the script is executed in that is protected.